# Complete the missing values of the cross product matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, machine-learning

A response variable $Y$ in terms of two predictors $X$ and $Z$. There are $n$
observations. Let $X$ be a matrix formed by a constant term of $1$, and the vectors $x$ and $z$. Consider the cross-product matrix $X^TX$ given below:

$$\begin{bmatrix}30 & 0 & 0\\\ ?&10&7 \\\ ? & ? &15\end{bmatrix}$$

What are the missing values denoted by “?”, determine the value of $n$ and calculate the linear correlation coefficient between $X$ and $Z$.

Comment: $X^TX$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't written 100% clearly, so I'm going to assume for now that the matrix $X$ is an $n \times 3$ matrix that looks like this

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & z_1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & x_n & z_n
\end{bmatrix}

Then 
\begin{align}
X'X &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \dots & 1 \\
x_1 & \dots & x_n \\
z_1 & \dots & z_n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & z_1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & x_n & z_n
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^n 1 & \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i & \sum_{i = 1}^n z_i \\
\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i & \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 & \sum_{i = 1}^n x_iz_i \\
\sum_{i = 1}^n z_i & \sum_{i = 1}^n x_iz_i & \sum_{i = 1}^n z_i^2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

So we know $n$ from the $[1,1]$ entry of the matrix, which allows us to calculate $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{z}$. We can then use the other entries in the matrix to calculate the correlation coefficient (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)

Little linear algebra trick, $X^TX$ is symmetric, so even without doing any math you can figure out what all the "?" are